# Momentum space calculation of observables

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, momentum, fourier-transform

In Griffiths *Introduction to Quantum Mechanics*, it is stated that the expectation value of any observable can be calculated in the momentum space Fourier space) in the following way.

> In momentum space, then, the position operator is $i\hbar\partial/\partial p$. More generally,
>   $$
> \langle Q\left(x,\,p\right)\rangle=\cases{\int\psi^\star\hat{Q}\left(x,\,\frac{\hbar}{i}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right)\psi\,{\rm d}x & \text{in position space;} \\ \int\Phi^\star\hat{Q}\left(-\frac{\hbar}{i}\frac{\partial}{\partial p},\,p\right)\Phi\,{\rm d}p & \text{in momentum space.}}\tag{3.58}
> $$
>   In principle, you can do all the calculations in momentum space just as well (though not always as *easily*) as in position space.

Can anyone show the proof of this statement?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can write the state in the position space as

$$\psi(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int\tilde{\psi}(k)e^{ikx}dk$$

Therefore, for example

$$\int\psi^{\ast}(x)x\psi(x)dx=\int\left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int\tilde{\psi}^{\ast}(k_{1})e^{-ik_{1}x}dk_{1}\right]x\left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int\tilde{\psi}(k_{2})e^{ik_{2}x}dk_{2}\right]dx=$$

$$=\int\tilde{\psi}^{\ast}(k_{1})\tilde{\psi}(k_{2})\left[\frac{1}{2\pi}\int xe^{i(k_{2}-k_{1})x}dx\right]dk_{1}dk_{2}=$$

$$=\int\tilde{\psi}^{\ast}(k_{1})\tilde{\psi}(k_{2})\frac{1}{i}\frac{\partial}{\partial k_{2}}\left[\frac{1}{2\pi}\int e^{i(k_{2}-k_{1})x}dx\right]dk_{1}dk_{2}=$$

$$=\int\tilde{\psi}^{\ast}(k_{1})\tilde{\psi}(k_{2})\frac{1}{i}\frac{\partial}{\partial k_{2}}\delta(k_{2}-k_{1}) dk_{1}dk_{2}=\left[{\rm integration\:by\:parts}\right]=$$

$$=\int\delta(k_{2}-k_{1})\tilde{\psi}^{\ast}(k_{1})\left(-\frac{1}{i}\frac{\partial}{\partial k_{2}}\right)\tilde{\psi}(k_{2})dk_{1}dk_{2}=$$

$$=\int\tilde{\psi}^{\ast}(k)\left(-\frac{1}{i}\frac{\partial}{\partial k}\right)\tilde{\psi}(k)dk=\int\tilde{\psi}^{\ast}(p)\left(-\frac{\hbar}{i}\frac{\partial}{\partial p}\right)\tilde{\psi}(p)dp$$

Can you generalize this result?

Answer (score 5):

To calculate an expectation value like $$ \langle\psi| \hat Q |\psi\rangle$$ you would like to represent the states and the operator in a given basis, say $\{|x\rangle\}$, by inserting two unities (build out of the basis elements) $$ \langle\psi| \mathbb{1}\hat Q  \mathbb{1}|\psi\rangle.$$ Since the Fourier transformation is akin to regular linear algebra change of basis operations, the representation in momentum space is equivalent.

Answer (score 3):

The wave functions in position and momentum are related via Fourier transform
$$\Psi(x)=\frac{1}{(2\pi\hbar)^{n/2}}\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}\tilde{\Psi}(p)\exp{\Big(\frac{ipx}{\hbar}\Big)}d^{(n)}p$$
The expectation value of the observable in position space is
$$\bar{O}=\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}\Psi^{\dagger}(x)O(x, -i\hbar\partial_{x})\Psi(x)d^{(n)}x=$$
$$=\frac{1}{(2\pi\hbar)^{n}}\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}\exp{\Big(\frac{-ipx}{\hbar}\Big)}\tilde{\Psi}^{\dagger}(p)O(x, -i\hbar\partial_{x})\tilde{\Psi}(q)\exp{\Big(\frac{iqx}{\hbar}\Big)}d^{(n)}pd^{(n)}qd^{(n)}x=$$
$$=\frac{1}{(2\pi\hbar)^{n}}\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}\tilde{\Psi}^{\dagger}(p)O(i\hbar\partial_{q}, q)\tilde{\Psi}(q)\exp{\Big(\frac{i(q-p)x}{\hbar}\Big)}d^{(n)}pd^{(n)}qd^{(n)}x=$$
$$=\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}\tilde{\Psi}^{\dagger}(p)O(i\hbar\partial_{q}, q)\tilde{\Psi}(q)\delta(p-q)d^{(n)}pd^{(n)}q=$$
$$=\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}\tilde{\Psi}^{\dagger}(p)O(i\hbar\partial_{p}, p)\tilde{\Psi}(p)d^{(n)}p$$